How to use MS Azure Key Vaults in stand-alone .NET (C#) applications
I'm confused. So I have a rough understanding of the MS Azure Key Vault concept and I would like to use it in a stand-alone C# Windows application. At the moment, just developing on one machine, I have my keys and endpoint set in my local Environment Variables.
Now I would like to build my application and give it to someone else. Obviously, I do not want my keys and secrets in my code so I want to use a Key Vault.
Looking at examples and tutorials I only ever see instructions for a local developer machine or an Azure WebApp. The local solution requires the Azure CL to authenticate and then use C# with your Key Vault name etc to retrieve keys and secrets. So far so good.
But how to access the vault from my C# code in a stand-alone app on someone else's computer who does not have (or want) the Azure CL nor has credentials to log in.
I hope I'm making sense here...
Looking up solutions, but they all need at least AZCL and authentication, while I was looking for a stand-alone application to be able to access the key vault

First of all you need to get your keyvault credential from the environment variable then using SecretClient you should pass the credential in order to access the secret.

All the idea to use the Key Vault is to protect the secure data from unauthorized access. How do you want to do it without identify the person/device that try to get access to it? Sure, there are solutions without login. You can create a Service Proncipal, give them the access to KV and integrate the Keys into your application, but you don't have any security any more by doing this.

If the user or environment is trusted, then you can use this approach. You can remove the permissions of the Service Principal any time, so may by it is little bit more secure, but only in trusted environment. You can integrate the ClientId, ClientSecrete and the TennantId into application settings and use the ClientSecretCredential class to access the KV

Thanks all! I guess that does make it clearer. I thought as much. Without a form of authentication of the user (or machine) it cannot be really secure. And if you are authenticating you probably don't really need all the extra protection.
Bottom line is that it is not possible to create an application that securely accesses KVs and so of that application is 'out there in the wild' without further authentication.
Thanks again!

Relying on environment variables for authentication is not recommended because it exposes authentication information to every application if set for the user. Even if you consider no security boundaries are crossed maliciously, any application that uploads a process dump for diagnostics would contain that information.
Instead, you should use the DefaultAzureCredential in Azure.Identity. We designed this to work for both production code as well as developer workflows. Interactive logins are disabled by default, but you can enable them as shown in the example below. The example will try to use a myriad of different techniques including the Azure CLI, but will fallback to opening the browser to authenticate the user using Microsoft authentication services.
﻿using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

Uri vaultUri = new(args.FirstOrDefault() ?? throw new Exception("Key Vault URL required"));
DefaultAzureCredential credential = new(includeInteractiveCredentials: true);
SecretClient client = new(vaultUri, credential);
await foreach (SecretProperties props in client.GetPropertiesOfSecretsAsync())
{
    if (!props.Managed && props.Enabled.GetValueOrDefault())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(props.Name);
    }
}

This should work for most people across different platforms, as long as they have a browser installed and that can be launched automatically. It's also more secure than using environment variables.
